# adding scrollbars to pythoncard application

Tags: python, wxpython, scroll, pythoncard

scrollingwindow as main frame for the application is not supported yet for pythoncard. how can i add scrollbars to main frame(background)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive never used pythoncard but in pure wxpython you can just put a ScrolledWindow inside the frame, then use a sizer to controll the scrollbars (asumming the contents of the sizer dont fit in the window). Eg this short code snipit will give you a window with a vertical scrollbar.

```
class Scrolled(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, size=(200,200))
        self.SetScrollRate(0, 10);
        sizerV = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #create a bunch of stuff in the sizer which doesnt fit
        for i in range(0,50):
            text = "Line: " + str(i)
            sizerV.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=text), 0)

        self.SetSizer(sizerV)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(200,200), Scrolled(self)
            title="Scroll Bars", style=wx.CAPTION)
```

Comment: in fact there's no support for scrolling in PythonCard as mentioned by the maintainer. and that made me convert the code to pure wx from pythoncard, using scrolledpanels.  thnaks for reply